# Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html file error when i try host expose

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

when i try to make laravel 9 vue3 shareable on my netwrok
i open expose
php artisan serve --host 
npm run dev --host 
its show error
(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.

and the page dont work as usual
and i dont know where is the wrong
my vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
 
});
```

Comment: I had this case once when I was using Typescript and had to replace 'resources/js/app.js' with 'resources/js/app.ts'. Like the error says, the "entry point" was missing. 
Another important aspect is that vue imports vue must have the .vue extension included (e.g. import JetButton from '@/Jetstream/Button.vue'). Otherwise the page throws an error and you see nothing.

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to run your application on the Local area network and facing this issue, please disable the windows firewall & network protection,
*You can run your laravel application on LAN with these commands:

```
php artisan serve –-host=192.168.xx.xx --port=8000

npm run dev  use --host to expose
```

And your Vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
        template: {
            transformAssetUrls: {
                base: null,
                includeAbsolute: false,
            },
        },
    }),

],
server: {
    host: true
}
optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
        define: {
            global: 'globalThis',
        },
        plugins: [
            NodeModulesPolyfills(),
            GlobalsPolyfills({
                process: true,
                buffer: true,
            }),
        ]
    },
},});
```